# Cannot compile Kafka consumer in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want to consume messages from Kafka topic using Scala `2.10.6` and Spark `1.6.2`. For Kafka I am using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This code compiles fine, however I want to define `auto.offset.reset` and here the problem arises:

```
val topicMap = topic.split(",").map((_, kafkaNumThreads.toInt)).toMap
val data = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap,
                             StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2).map(_._2)
```

When I add `kafkaParams`, it does not compile anymore:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
"zookeeper.connect" -> zkQuorum, "group.id" -> group,
"zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "10000",
"auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")

val data = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, kafkaParams, topicMap,
                                 StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2).map(_._2)
```

Error message:

```
94: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$3) => x$3._2)
[ERROR]                                                 StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2).map(_._2)
```

I tried many different cominations of parameters of `createStream`, but everything fails. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add type parameters to `KafkaUtils.createStream` for it to resolve the underlying types of the stream. For example, if your key and value are of type `String`:

```
val data: DStream[String] =
  KafkaUtils
    .createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
       ssc,
       kafkaParams,
       topicMap,
       StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2
  ).map(_._2)
```

Comment: Ok, let me check it. Indeed the problem is that I want to consume messages from remote Kafka queue. I can get them using `curl` command and confluent API from terminal. But I don't get them if I run Scala code. So, my assumption is that I need to specify the offset.

Comment: @Dinosaurius The error in your question has nothing to do with offsets. It's simply the compiler not able to infer the correct type.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just wanted to explain why do I need to set the offset.

Comment: The code compiles now. Thanks. P.S. I know it's unrelated to the posted question, but I really appreciate if you can suppose why the Kafka messages do not appear when I use this code in Scala (no error is given). May it happen that I consumed them all from terminal using `curl`. Which are the parameters (besides offset) that may influence? IP and port are the same. Maybe, group?

Comment: @Dinosaurius Is this your full code? Meaning is this all you do with the `StreamingContext`?

Comment: No, I then write raw data to S3 (and it worked in my tests with local Kafka; it does nothing when using remote Kafka): `data.window(Seconds(300), Seconds(300)).foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
      val day = sdf_day.format(new Date(time.milliseconds))
      val hourmin = sdf_sec.format(new Date(time.milliseconds))
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("s3n://" + bucketNameData + "/" + stream_folder + "/" + day + "/" + hourmin)
    }`

Comment: Do you call `start` and `awaitTermination` on the `StreamingContext`?

Comment: Yes, I have this at the end: `ssc.remember(Seconds(300))

    ssc.start()

    ssc.awaitTermination()

    Thread.sleep(3000)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131698/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-dinosaurius).